# X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE” still not working properly

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, x-ua-compatible

My application doesn't support IE7 and IE8 .But its working fine in IE9 and IE10.So I used this

```
 <head runat="server">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7 ;IE=Edge" />
```

Now its working fine in my system.

But the problem is that my client has only IE7 and IE8. He doesn't have higher version of IE. For him my application is not supporting.So can anyone tell me where will be the issue ? Does this meta tag only work in IE which has higher version? Can anybody help me out?

Comment: This is far too vague, comparable to “my application is broken, how to fix it?” without giving any information about the application.

Comment: Yes..becoz i have higher version of IE.So its working fine in my system but nt in my client system becoz he has only IE7 and IE8

Answer (score 4):

You can use the meta tag to downgrade the rendering engine. For example if you have IE10, then you can emulate it in IE8,IE9 and all lower versions. But if you have IE8 then how come you ask it to run as IE9 or IE10? That's not possible.

Comment: Then what should i do? I have higher version but my client has not.So what should be meta tag statement can you please tell me?

Comment: `My application doesn't support IE7 and IE8.` That means if anyone uses IE7 or IE8 (not higher version than that) then your application will not work. Find out the reasons why doesn't your app work on IE7 and 8 and then try to resolve those. Else ask your customer to upgrade his IE. BTW does your app work fine on IE6?

Comment: But for me its supporting while m trying to run in IE7 and IE8 by using the above tag.

Comment: Your meta tag forces the browser to render as that particular version's standards. Since you have higher version it works fine, customer has IE7, or 8 so it tries to use that version only.

Comment: Thanks..but is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You will have to resolve issues in your application with IE7 and 8. That's the only possible solution.

Comment: Ideally you can get them to upgrade their systems and use enterprise mode for all their legacy applications they don't have time to upgrade, http://love2dev.com/#!article/Internet-Explorer-Enterprise-Mode-Resources. If they want to keep their company in the year 2007 then you need to write your web site to 2007 standards.